# What's the best way to store all these data in db?

Tags: mysql, analytics

My client has given me about 14k urls of various products and he wants me to store all the price changes of that product per day. I think it will require an immense amount of db storage and a lot of optimization. I've never done this before. I'm using mysql DB. Should I store all these price changes per product in a JSON column or as separate row? Looking for tips regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: Store it according to the best database normalization practices. If performance becomes a problem, look into redesigning it then. But most databases can handle many thousands of rows, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'm thinking about storing it in a json column of each product. Would this be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON columns are not as efficient as normal SQL columns and should be reserved for when you're not sure what data you're going to have. You're pretty sure what data you're going to have.

This is a pretty straightforward two table schema. One table for the product, and one for its price changes.

```
create table product (
    id integer primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar,
    url varchar unique,
    ...any other information about the product you might want to store...

    index(url)
);
```

By giving it a primary key it shields you from the URL changing, and it reduces the amount that must be stored in tables that refer to it. They only have to store the integer primary key, not the whole URL. The URL is indexed for faster searches.

Now that you have a product table other tables can refer to it. Like a table of price changes.

```
create table product_price_changes (
    product_id integer references product(id),
    price numeric(9,2) not null,
    change_time datetime not null,

    index(change_time)
);
```

This table stores when the price for a product changes, and what that price is. This is how you attach lists of data to things in SQL. The `change_time` is indexed for faster searches.

A simple join lets you efficiently see all the changes to a particular product in order.

```
select price, change_time
from product_price_changes ppc
join product prod on ppc.product_id = prod.id
where prod.url = ?
order by change_time
```

Comment: wouldn't the db size exceeds 100s of gbs by storing this way? 
thanks for writing such a detailed answer.

Comment: @user3407278 It's going to be similar total amount of data no matter how you organize it.

Comment: @user3407278 That depends on what and how much you're storing, but 100 GB is ***a lot*** of data. You can storage cost by looking at the [storage requirements for variable types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html). The product table is inconsequential, there's relatively few products compared to their changes. Each change is 4 (int) + 4 + 1 (numeric(9,2)) + 8 bytes (datetime) plus some overhead. So we're talking 20-30 bytes per price change. Plus the indexes. Very, very efficient.